# RIA Web service save data using stored procedure

Tags: web-services, stored-procedures, silverlight-4.0, ria

The application I am working on is using RIA Web service, stored procedures, and NHibernate as the ORM. I have been able to retrieve data, but I am now having problems with updating the data. I have come across this http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/172626/389010.aspx, and I've tried to set things up as suggested. So my code (simplified) is as follows:

```
 private void Save_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
 {
     _ctx.Load( _ctx.UpdateProdOrderByWorkCellIdAndDateListQuery( list ), SaveChanges, null );
 }

 private void SaveChanges(LoadOperation<OrderAndOperationAndWCData> obj)
 {
     _ctx.SubmitChanges();
 }
```

I've used Fiddler and I can confirm that a call to the Web service is made. However, the problem is that when I look in SQL Server Profiler, the save stored procedure never gets called. Can anyone provide any advice as to what could be going wrong?

--- Edit

I suspect that the way I'm calling the stored procedure is wrong. I've got something like this:

```
this.GetSession().CreateSQLQuery( "exec usp_Update @MyArray=:MyArray" )
            .AddEntity( typeof( OrderAndOperationAndWCData ) )
            .SetParameter( "MyArray", list );
```

Can anyone tell if that could be it?

Comment: Are any exceptions being thrown by the web service?

Comment: No none that I can tell or see.

Comment: From the lack of comments it would appear that I must not have given an important piece of info. Can anyone tell me how they'd go about debugging this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the answer and it was due to my lack of understanding/experiece with NHibernate. Effectively, in my code I had:

```
this.GetSession().CreateSQLQuery( "exec usp_Update @MyArray=:MyArray" )
        .AddEntity( typeof( OrderAndOperationAndWCData ) )
        .SetParameter( "MyArray", list );
```

But it should have been:

```
this.GetSession().CreateSQLQuery( "exec usp_Update @MyArray=:MyArray" )
            .AddEntity( typeof( OrderAndOperationAndWCData ) )
            .SetParameter( "MyArray", list )
            .ExecuteUpdate();
```

although I've now got an exception raised but that could well be to do with the sproc itself.